# Why this web application built with Clojure, ClojureSript, Figwheel, Lein is not been updated on the browser after editions on the source code?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, figwheel

I am watching a course/tutorial from Eric Normand on
[front-end](https://ericnormand.podia.com/clojurescript-frontend). The
course is a paid private service.

However, he is using a public repo on GitHub, [this
one](https://github.com/lispcast/understanding-re-frame).

After cloning and executing `lein fig-dev`, the project seems to have
been succesfully built:

```bash
2022-08-25 13:46:47.988:INFO::main: Logging initialized @3006ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
[Figwheel] Validating figwheel-main.edn
[Figwheel] figwheel-main.edn is valid \(ツ)/
[Figwheel] Compiling build dev to "resources/public/js/compiled/app.js"
[Figwheel] Successfully compiled build dev to "resources/public/js/compiled/app.js" in 1.33 seconds.
[Figwheel] Watching paths: ("src") to compile build - dev
[Figwheel:SEVERE] /private/var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/jna1153974339277798676.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/jna1153974339277798676.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/jna1153974339277798676.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have (unknown,i386,x86_64), need (arm64e)))
[Figwheel] Starting Server at http://localhost:3449
[Figwheel] Starting REPL
Prompt will show when REPL connects to evaluation environment (i.e. a REPL hosting webpage)
Figwheel Main Controls:
          (figwheel.main/stop-builds id ...)  ;; stops Figwheel autobuilder for ids
          (figwheel.main/start-builds id ...) ;; starts autobuilder focused on ids
          (figwheel.main/reset)               ;; stops, cleans, reloads config, and starts autobuilder
          (figwheel.main/build-once id ...)   ;; builds source one time
          (figwheel.main/clean id ...)        ;; deletes compiled cljs target files
          (figwheel.main/status)              ;; displays current state of system
Figwheel REPL Controls:
          (figwheel.repl/conns)               ;; displays the current connections
          (figwheel.repl/focus session-name)  ;; choose which session name to focus on
In the cljs.user ns, controls can be called without ns ie. (conns) instead of (figwheel.repl/conns)
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
    Exit: :cljs/quit
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, *e holds last exception object
Opening URL http://localhost:3449
ClojureScript 1.10.764

cljs.user=> (js/alert "hello")
nil
```

**This is all my log** (question was asked as comment below).

The browser starts (I am using Brave) and the application seems to be
succesfully loaded on `http://localhost:3449/`/.

I have a REPL working and I can even do alerts like that happen as
events on the browser at localhost:

```clj
cljs.user=> (js/alert "hello")
nil
```

Ok. The only problem is when I edit the sorce code as he does on the
videos. In his case, the changes make effect on the browser. On my
case, they do not. Nothing happens.

I can **only** see changes if **I rebuilt everything from scratch**.

In other projects, I managed to see the changes happening live, but I
was using `shadow-cljs` there.

How do I fix this?

Obs.: I am using Macbook M1, macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Comment: I can not confirm this behaviour.  From your log, is this _all_ or have you left out trailing lines?  There should be prompt `cljs.user=>` and then on changes `[Figwheel] Compiling build dev to "resources/public/js/compiled/app.js"
[Figwheel] Successfully compiled build dev to "resources/public/js/compiled/app.js" in 0.958 seconds.`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @cfrick. Unfortunately, there is no such message for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @SearCorfield, I managed to solve the problem.

Also, Eric Normand (the creator of the course and author of the
[repository](https://github.com/lispcast/understanding-re-frame)) has
just updated the `project.clj` file to have
`[com.bhauman/figwheel-main "0.2.18"]`. It now works smoothly!

Answer (score 5):

The Hawk filewatcher used in the version of `figwheel-main` you have does not support the M1 Mac -- that's what the JNA-related SEVERE error is about in the logs.

The current version of `figwheel-main` is 0.2.18 so you can try that instead of 0.2.12 in `project.clj`. According to the changelog, 0.2.14 switched from Hawk to Beholder so it may fix the M1 compatibility issue.

Comment: Thanks, @SeanCorfield. How did you find that out?  The error message is quite obscure to my naive eyes: `[Figwheel:SEVERE] /private/var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/jna1153974339277798676.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/jna1153974339277798676.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/jna1153974339277798676.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have (unknown,i386,x86_64), need (arm64e)))`. I am impressed with your answer.

Comment: "missing compatible architecture" and "need (arm64e)" were the clues for me, along with `jna` in the temp file path suggesting it's a Java native access issue. I don't do any ClojureScript myself but I've seen a few people run into this issue (Hawk) with macOS updates as well.